# Drop-down summary reputation did not zero out when new day began

Tags: support, bug, status-declined

I noticed last night (and it is still the case today) that when I clicked on the arrow next to my name to see the dropbox with the summary, that the reputation count included the amount from yesterday, instead of zeroing out when the "new day" began.

Here's a screenshot of the dropdown taken a few minutes ago:

[image]

You can see the "290" total.

Here's the reputation summary, showing that 230 of those points belong to yesterday, 60 to today:

[image]

Comment: I just noticed I have the same problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reputation will be off until tomorrow, apologies but this isn't an easy thing to fix - and given it wasn't a week, month, quarter, or year change...it'll fix itself completely tonight.

I'm sure you'll see a post-mortem of some sort about this later from our sysadmins, but we <s>have</s> had a particular web server that runs our scheduled jobs, or kicks them off rather.  Unfortunately this server ate it (repeatedly) last night before the reputation reset job got kicked off, so it didn't happen precisely at 00:00 UTC as it normally does.

We're not sure of the cause yet (diagnostics on the troubled hardware are underway) but we did some scrambling to get things back in working order, so everything should be good from here on out.

I'm going to [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) this, but I hope you'll agree it's simply not worth the half-day time investment to fix the numbers *just* for a day already half over.

Comment: Certainly; given what you say, I can just wait. But since I didn't notice anyone bringing this up, I just wanted to alert the sysadmins in case it was caused by something else. Thanks for letting us know what was up.